# Embedding videos with JavaHelp

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on something similar to NetBeans "help contents" after clicking "Help" button(the button shown on the top right of NetBeans IDE).  I want to know if the "help contents" can embed videos or not.

In particular, the questions are:

1. What version of JavaHelp is used in NetBeans 8.0?
2. What JavaHelp renderer is provided by default in NetBeans?
3. Do any versions of JavaHelp support embedded video or flash objects?

If the "help contents" can embed videos,  how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**3 Do any versions of JavaHelp support embedded video or flash objects**

Yes according to this [userGuide](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/jhug.pdf) page 31

> A Java developer can create new lightweight components as well. For example, a such a component might
>   add functionality like animation and multimedia to help topics. The Java
>   TM
>   2 Platform includes high quality
>   audio as well as a video viewer that supports the common formats. For more information see Creating
>   Lightweight Components.

You can create a simple html document which loads a video and load it via JavaHelp HTMLViewer.

Comment: Hi Madhan, I tried to embed videos in JavaHelp using "iframe" and "object" tags.  By using "iframe", the "help contents" did not display anything. By using "object" tag, the "help contents" displayed "??" red mark.  Would you be able to provide some suggestions?

Comment: Well this is from the Official doc.But if the html is dynamic or too complex it won't render properly